# jQuery Cycle2 plugin with carousel not working; no errors in console

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm trying to use the jQuery Cycle2 plugin on a site and I am very new to jQuery so it's very hard to troubleshoot.  I don't see any errors in the JavaScript console.  My code is below and [I also made a jsfiddle here which passed validation](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5cvq/1/).  It works locally but when I plug it into OpenCMS, the slides in the carousel are out of their container and sized at 100%, and nothing is clickable (meaning even clicking the oversized carousel images does not change the slide in the first div which is sitting behind everything).

The site I'm plugging this into is running jQuery 1.3.2 and I don't have the ability to change or update that, so I used noConflict.  Before I used noConflict, other parts of the site were breaking AND the slider wouldn't work. Now the other parts of the site are OK but the slider still won't function.

The slider uses the data attribute on the divs to pass the options, and I thought maybe it wasn't working because the site doctype is XHTML 1.0.  But when I change the doc type on my local file to match the site I'm working with, the slider still works.

I also tried [following the instructions here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) to set the options programatically but I couldn't get that to work even on my local machine...I think I don't know enough JavaScript to write the code properly.

I am stumped and too inexperienced to know how to troubleshoot this without any help.  Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <title>Soleil Cycle2 Carousel Pager</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>   
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var jQuery_1_9_0 = $.noConflict(true);
            jQuery_1_9_0(document).ready(function($){
            var slideshows = $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function(e, opts) {
                slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
            });

            $('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){
                var index = $('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
                slideshows.cycle('goto', index);
            });

            });
            </script> 
            <style type="text/css">
            #soleil-intro * { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
            #soleil-intro #cycle-1 div { width:950px; }
            #soleil-intro #cycle-2 .cycle-slide { border:3px solid #fff; }
            #soleil-intro #cycle-2 .cycle-slide-active { border:3px solid #f6d609; }
            #soleil-intro #soleil-slideshow-1 { max-width: 980px; margin: auto; z-index: 1; position: relative; }
            #soleil-intro #soleil-slideshow-2 { max-width: 940px; margin: auto; z-index: 1; position: relative; margin-top: 10px;  }
            #soleil-intro .cycle-slideshow img { width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; }
            #soleil-intro .arrow {float: left; width: 15px; position: relative; top: 200px;}
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="soleil-intro">
            <div id="soleil-slideshow-1">
                <p class="arrow">
                    <a href="#" class="cycle-prev">&laquo;</a> 
                </p>
                <div style="float: left;" id="cycle-1" class="cycle-slideshow"
                    data-cycle-slides="> div"
                    data-cycle-timeout="0"
                    data-cycle-prev="#soleil-slideshow-1 .cycle-prev"
                    data-cycle-next="#soleil-slideshow-1 .cycle-next"
                    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
                    >
                    <div><img src="../soleil1.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>
                    <div><a href="test.html"><img src="../soleil2.jpg" width="980" height="425"></a></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil3.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil4.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil5.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil3.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil4.jpg" width="980" height="425"></div>      
                </div>
                    <p class="arrow">
                    <a href="#" class="cycle-next"><img src="../arrow.gif" style="display:inline;" alt="arrow" height="12" width="16" border="0" /></a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div id="soleil-slideshow-2" style="clear: both;">
                <div id="cycle-2" class="cycle-slideshow"
                    data-cycle-slides="> div"
                    data-cycle-timeout="0"
                    data-cycle-prev="#soleil-slideshow-2 .cycle-prev"
                    data-cycle-next="#soleil-slideshow-2 .cycle-next"
                    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
                    data-cycle-carousel-visible="3"
                    data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true"
                    data-allow-wrap="false"
                    >
                    <div><img src="../soleil1.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil2.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil3.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil4.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil5.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil3.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <div><img src="../soleil4.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- #soleil-intro -->
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the right paths to the images,css and javascript? Also do they actually exist on the server?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If you look at the fiddle, it works there perfectly.

Comment: What you're showing us is not going to solve your problem. This is just the example code. I grabbed it and changed the paths and it worked fine. Apparently we will need to see the actual code - where you're inserting it and probably some css as well.

Comment: What I've pasted is what I put into OpenCMS, minus the html, head, and body tags. I haven't even begun to worry about the CSS yet.  I don't have a way I can show you the full page, unfortunately.  Really wish I did because this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Okey, what browser are you using? Do you have a debugging tool in the browser ? (For example in Firefox you need to install Firebug, as for Chrome the debugging tool is integrated. Just press F12 and see if a sidewindow will popup in either browsers)

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you have mentioned which CMS you are integrating it into,
use this code :

Needed to paste the noConflict right after the jquery.1.9 file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            var jQuery_1_9_0 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>   


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery_1_9_0(document).ready(function(){
        var slideshows = jQuery_1_9_0('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function(e, opts) {
            slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
        });

        jQuery_1_9_0('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){
            var index = jQuery_1_9_0('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
            slideshows.cycle('goto', index);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully it would solve the problem.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5cvq/8/

Comment: I'm using OpenCMS, updated the question to include that.  The code you provided didn't fix it, unfortunately.  Thanks for trying, I appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's on a dev environment right now.  I can post it on my own personal URL but it works there :\

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I'm not even sure how to do that. I mean, I know how to use alert and (console.log()) to some degree but I'm not sure where to put it in my page to get it to tell me anything useful. I need some classes!

Comment: Inside the document.ready function you could alert. I think the slider is not initialized at all due to conflict of different jquery library versions

Comment: If you are still on..  <script type="text/javascript">var jQuery_1_9_0= jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>  right after you have used the 1.9 version and before pasting the js files for the plugin

Comment: I added an alert in my original script, immediately after jQuery_1_9_0(document).ready(function(){  and the alert popped up as soon as the images appeared for the slider.  Then, I removed the alert and added the script you suggested above, which resulted in several TypeErrors in the console.  I'll be on all day if you have any more ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

This question came up in a search to troubleshoot my own jquery cycle2 issues, but just in passing, you have a typo in the opening DIV tag of your slideshow containers. In the value field of the 'data-cycle-slides' attribute, the right angle bracket is closing the DIV open tag too soon. it should be:

```
<div style="float: left;" id="cycle-1" class="cycle-slideshow"
                data-cycle-slides="div"
                data-cycle-timeout="0"
                data-cycle-prev="#soleil-slideshow-1 .cycle-prev"
                data-cycle-next="#soleil-slideshow-1 .cycle-next"
                data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
                >
```

Comment: I believe that her `data-cycle-slides="> div"` is actually correct. Take a look here and you will see an example of this type of cycle2 configuration: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php

Comment: This answer is incorrect and should not be used. The angle bracket is the CSS direct child selector and is required for custom slides to work unless you use another select such as a class name.

Comment: @maidbloke and 3rror404, you are both correct. What's the convention here on stackOverflow when you've provided an incorrect answer? Should I remove it?